# How to fetch the current logged-in user name from the application without using ActiveX control?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, internet-explorer, activexobject

I have a unified desktop web application from where I need to fetch the username of the logged-in user and need to place it in any custom UI. The application needs to be opened din IE 11. ActiveX settings are disabled as kept for security reasons..

Kindly suggest any alternative approach which will fulfil the requirement. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you won't be able to do that due to security reasons. If this is something that's part of an intranet, then you can achieve what you're looking for with Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
</script>
```

This is how to do it in JavaScript for IE11